# If a user has been deleted, delete also the user's files

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know how to delete the files uploaded by the user after he/she has been deleted.

Whenever I delete a user, it only deletes the data on the database. But I want is to also delete the files in the file system.

> NOTE: I'm using Wordpress. rmdir() and unlink() isn't working.

Please help! I tried Googling it, but there's nothing.

UPDATE: Thanks to pr1nc3 for the function.

But it's not yet done.

```
add_action( 'delete_user', 'delete_user_dir' );
function delete_user_dir( $user_id ) {
 global $wpdb;

 $files = 'wp-content/uploads/user/';
 $deluser = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT user_login FROM " .$wpdb->user ." WHERE ID=".$user_id ); 
}
```

**wp-content/uploads/user/Array** <- **OUTPUT**

For the `rmdir()` and `unlink` it works. But it can't find the path I want to delete because of this.

I found on my research I need to move the `global $wpdb` before the function is fired. But it returns an error...
**Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object**.

Comment: ` rmdir() and unlink() isn't working.`, but why?

Comment: Check the file and folder permission..

Comment: Are any of the user's files left in the media library? http://en.support.wordpress.com/media/deleting-files/

Comment: @Raj Mohan CHMOD doesn't have to do with it because the parent directory is already 777. I just need is whenever an administrator deletes a member of the site, it also automatically delete the user's folder. But thanks for that suggestion.

Comment: @DavidEugenePeterson the files are inside a subdirectory in the wp-content directory. The files are uploaded straight to the database and file system.

Comment: I think you need to hot code the folder and file delete in the action of delete user....

Comment: @xdazz I don't know. But maybe, I just put it in the wrong function. If that's it, I can't find the wp_delete_user function inside wp-includes/user.php

Comment: @RajMohan I'm using 3.7.1. 3.8 has that kind of function but I'm not permitted to upgrade it to 3.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! Thanks for the help guys. :)

```
function delete_user_dir( $user_id ) {

 global $wpdb;
 $url = home_url('/');
 $folder = 'wp-content/uploads/user/';
 $deluser = get_userdata( $user_id );

 $files = glob($url. $folder . $deluser->user_login .'/*');

 if(is_array($files)){
    foreach($files as $file){ 
      if(is_file($file))
        unlink($file);
    };

    rmdir($url. $folder . $deluser->user_login .'/'); 

 }else{
    rmdir($url. $folder . $deluser->user_login .'/*'); 
 }
}

add_action( 'delete_user', 'delete_user_dir' );
```

Answer (score 1):

**This Function Would run everytime when user is deleted**

**`$user_id` is id of that deleted user**

```
 function my_delete_user( $user_id ) {
    --> Get All posts created by $user_id
    --> Loop All posts to get attachments for each posts 
    --> Finally delete each attachment using wp_delete_attachment   

    }

add_action( 'delete_user', 'my_delete_user' );
```

**Refer here
[Delete Attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_attachment)**